# Hostname for website running inside Docker

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker and my question is similar to:

[My websites running in docker containers, how to implement virtual host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519215/my-websites-running-in-docker-containers-how-to-implement-virtual-host)

But I don't actually need to host multiple sites with different virtual hosts.  I just need to get the server to respond to a particular virtual host name, eg: myhost.mysite.com

Right now the site works fine via IP but won't respond when I use the host name.  Since I only have the one site/hostname do I have to setup a proxy as described in the question?

I've tried adding a -h 'myhost.mysite.com' to my docker run command but that didn't seem to make any difference.

PS.  hostname DNS does correctly resolve to the IP address of the docker server.

Answer (score 2):

That really depends on the web server running inside the container.

- Apache: use `ServerName` and possibly `ServerAlias`
- Nginx: use `server_name`
- Django: use `ALLOWED_HOSTS`

Really, Docker doesn't need to know. The HTTP server software needs to know.

The question you linked to deals with multiple sites, which is why a proxy was needed. If you are only running one site, a proxy is not necessary (at least, not for this purpose). Just let Docker listen on port 80 and/or 443 itself, and let the server software running inside decide what hostname(s) are valid for the site.